# Arrays.equals without length of arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays with different length, but same elements. For example

```
A1 = {1,2,3,null,null}
A2 = {1,2,3}
```

Arrays.equals gives me false, because arrays have different length. Are there any method in java that will compare only elements in method?
I don't want to use .toString
I'm trying to make compare method in my own generic stack realization.

Comment: You could also compare the length. Besides that, does the array only have primitive types?

Comment: So you want to only compare the non-null elements? So `{ 1, 2, 3, null }` and `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }` are not equal, but `{ 1, null, 2, 3 }` and `{ 1, 2, null, 3 }` are?

Comment: @LinFelix it's generic array.

Comment: @Sweeper Second variant is impossible, because I'm writing my own stack. So,only top elements can be null

Comment: Have you considered `A1.length == A2.length && Arrays.deepEquals(A1, A2)`?

Comment: @LinFelix No, OP meant that there can only be trailing nulls. The stack grows towards the end of the array.

Comment: You can use a filter to filter all non-null elements in the first step and then compare your arrays (which only consist of numbers then) in the second step.

Comment: `Arrays.compare(A1,0,3,A2,0,3)==0`?

Comment: @MBPictures How do I use this filter right? I'm new in java and i haven't heard about this before...

Comment: Are you implementing something like a `equals(T[])` method in your stack? If so, can it be assumed that one of the arrays will not have trailing nulls? I would also suggest that you edit the fact that you are implementing a stack into your question, and include more context about why you need this exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because its a weird request. `null` does not mean 'not here', `null` means 'unknown / unset', that's why it throws exceptions when you interact with it: You're asking "hey, thing that has not been set yet, are you X", and there is no way to answer such a question.

That doesn't mean your code is wrong, just, you can stop looking for existing implementations. Weird requests generally aren't catered to by the core libraries (or any other). You also may want to change your mindset on `null`. Programming in java is a lot less aggravating if at all times a NullPointerException is a good thing. In other words, avoid using `null` as having any semantic meaning. If you ever write `if (x == null || x.isEmpty())` you are doing it wrong. Instead, where-ever 'x' is coming from, it should hold, or be updated to ASAP, the empty string instead. So, if reading in external data (e.g. you marshalled some JSON into an object), do a 'clean' step that replaces all `null` values that have semantic meaning with an object that actually represents it, and for methods that return stuff, always return an object that represents what you are returning - only return `null` if you *WANT* to convey the notion that there is no result (i.e. that's not the same as 'an empty result', i.e. if any code acts like there was a result, you *want* it to crash).

In other words, I doubt you are asking the right question. But in case you are, you have two broad options.

### First make null-less arrays then compare those as normal

One option is to make new arrays that have nulls stripped. Something like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<T> T[] stripNulls(T[] in) {
  Class<?> componentType = in.getClass().getComponentType();

  return (T[]) Arrays.stream(in)
    .filter(x -> x != null)
    .toArray(len -> java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(componentType, len));
}

// which you can then use; you don't need generics for a compare,
// it wouldn't add anything at all.

boolean compare(Object[] a, Object[] b) {
  return Arrays.equals(stripNulls(a), stripNulls(b));
}
```

### Just compare in place

If it's performance sensitive that's suboptimal. A better approach would involve a little more coding:

```
boolean compare(Object[] a, Object[] b) {
  Object ae = null, be = null;
  int ai = 0, bi = 0, al = a.length, bl = b.length;

  while (true) {
    /* set `ae` and `be` to the next non-null element */
    while (ae == null && ai < al) ae = a[ai++];
    while (be == null && bi < bl) be = b[bi++];

    /* Have we hit the end? */
    if (ai == al && bi == bl) return true;

    /* If one is at the end, but the other isn't... */
    if (ai == al || bi == bl) return false;

    /* check if the 2 current elements are equal */
    if (!ae.equals(be)) return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the standard comparison mechanism that we teach in computer science classes with an `isPalindrome` (without reversing) challenge.

Comment: Can I save generic part of my arrays this method? (sorry that i haven't mentioned this immediately).  I mean, to change Object[] to T[] somehow

Comment: The `compare` method returns a boolean. There is simply nothing to preserve!

Comment: I edited the answer to show how a stripNulls method can preserve generics. Not sure why you need that for a comparison operation, though.

Answer (score -1):

Not a native Java Developer, but maybe this helps you?

```
boolean arraysEqual = Arrays.equals(Arrays.stream(a1).filter(n => n != null).toArray(), Arrays.stream(a2).filter(n => n != null).toArray())
```

Comment: That snippet is rather broken. For example, the first param is a Stream, which you can't pass to Arrays.equals

Comment: Thanks for the hint, little oopsi on my end.